# chartjs align origin of the axis to the corner of graph

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, alignment, chart.js

I am new to java script and now having some troubles when I try to draw charJS graph in a very small boxes.

My intended behavior is to make the origin of the coordinate of the graph locate at the left-bottom corner of canvas, so the canvas is fully utilized.
Current behavior as below,

[image]

Intended behavior as below,

[image]

Here is what I have tried in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4qx8f2z/). The origin of graph is not aligned to the left corner of the axis and I have no idea on how to change the location of the axis origin.

javascript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext('2d');

var data = {
labels: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5 ,
    6 ,
    7 ,
    8 ,
    9 ,
    10
],
datasets: [{
    label: "Project",
    fill:false,
    borderColor:"#F83435",
    borderWidth:1,
    data: [
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
    6,
7,
8,
8,
9, ],
} 
]};

var options = {
elements:{point:{radius:0}},
responsive:true,
scales:{
    xAxes:[{gridLines:{display:false, color: "#FFFFFF"},
        ticks:{display:false}}],
        yAxes:[{gridLines:{display:false, color: "#FFFFFF"},
        ticks:{display:false}}]
},    
legend:{display:false}

}

var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options:options});
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<canvas id="lineChart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:blue;
}
```

Kindly help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it is me being stupid, just need to hide the entire axis then the result is correct. Like,

```
scales:{
       xAxes:[{display:false, }],
       yAxes:[{display:false,}]},    
       legend:{display:false}
}
```